# Run python script by bash with additional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, ubuntu

Run python script by bash with additional arguments

Hello,

I want to run a python script using bash that contains several arguments: example: `python3 stw_apiv6.py -E var1 -a '2023-10-19 16:00' -b '2023-10-20 16:00' -r yes`, It's how it should normally run in the terminal.

When doing it with bash I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
time=$(date +"%H:%M")
hours1=$(date -d "1 hour ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
quote=" ' "
complete=$quote$date" "$time$quote
echo "Hours : $hours"
echo "Hours1 : $hours1"
echo "date : $date"
echo "hour : $hour"
echo "complete : $complete"
python3 stw_apiv6.py -a $full
exit
```

Where I try to nest the date in a single variable. When I run I have this error

It must be executed as in cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dsqQ.png)

Comment: It's easier to read if you post a text version of the error message instead of a screengrab. Also the question might be more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Read [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Very short summary: Quotes that are data don't substitute for quotes that are syntax. (They aren't interchangeable in more conventional languages like Python either; why people assume they _do_ substitute for each other in bash is... a bit of a headscratcher)

Comment: Anyhow, you should be using an array rather than a string to store and pass your arguments, and BashFAQ #50 describes how to do so.

Comment: (and next time, copy-and-paste error messages _as text_; we don't count screenshots towards meeting [mre] requirements for the reasons given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122); see the way I edited your question to format the code correctly -- the same mechanism, pretty much, can be used to correctly format textual logs and error messages)